# How to format the retrieve MySQL data to make it like a subdirectory of a domain using PHP

Tags: php

I am very curious on how to make a site built using php and mysql. When i try to retrieve username from mysql how can i format it like this, very similar to facebook or twitter (note: i am not making social networking site here, i just like the idea and i think it is very helpful)..

```
mydomain.com/username
```

at first, i thought i should make a sub-directory to all the usernames.. but wait, what if i have tons of usernames in the database how can i make directories in each usernames? so i think somebody might help me here..

or like on a blog.. how can i make the title of the post like this:

```
mydomain.com/title-of-the-post
```

i'm new to php..
you can freely edit this question if this is ambiguous or not easy to understand i just can't find the exact word for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a router [e.g. [klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php)], and to apply the [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) in order to route all incoming requests to the entrance of your application.

No directory nor filesystem should be involved at all.

Comment: is Front Controller Pattern the same with MVC?

Comment: They are orthogonal topics - you can use MVC with querystrings [e.g. `index.php?controller=posts&action=show&id=1`]. Btw web frameworks are rather request/response driven, that MVC: don't stick to buzzwords, but to strategies you know for sure they do work ; ))

Answer (score 0):

You write a PHP routine to parse the URL.

So that the URL reaches the PHP routine, you make all /username, /title-of-post etc point to this routine using .htaccess - typically directing all traffic for anything that doesn't exist as a file or directory to your index.php file.

Comment: so this might be more simpler than using Front Controller Pattern or a router as what @moonwave99 said a while ago?

Comment: This *is* how you cobble together a basic router for a Front Controller thing. I'm just outlining what you need to do rather than telling you the names of the concepts. The earlier response answers your "can't find the exact word for this" rather than "how".